# View the data contained in the ClientDataSet in the table

Tags: delphi

I need your help. I have a ClientDataSet and a TDBGrid table. For the first time I am building a table. What? I'm still missing here to view the data.

```
   Procedure TForm1.AddLanguageGrid();
 var  lWord: Tword;
 lColumn: TColumn
 begin

  self.ClientDataSet1 := TClientDataSet.Create(self);
  self.ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Brand_trousers', ftstring, 100);
  self.ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Color', ftstring, 100);

  self.ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  self.ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'id';
  self.ClientDataSet1.DisableControls;
  self.DataSource1.DataSet := self.ClientDataSet1;
  self.DBGrid1.DataSource := self.DataSource1;
  self.DBGrid1.Columns.Clear;    

  lColumn := TColumn.Create(self.DBGrid1.Columns);
  lColumn.Width := 40;
  lColumn.Title.Caption := 'Brand trousers';
  lColumn.FieldName := 'Brand_trousers';

  lColumn := TColumn.Create(self.DBGrid1.Columns);
  lColumn.Width := 150;
  lColumn.Title.Caption := 'Color';
  lColumn.FieldName := 'Color';

self.ClientDataSet1.Append;
self.ClientDataSet1.EnableControls;
end.
```

Comment: When are you going to learn that you don't need all these `self`s?  And what is your question?

Comment: What, apart from the fact that you forgot to add any non-null data to the CDS so there is nothing to display?

Answer (score 3):

The following works fine for me:

```
procedure TForm1.AddLanguage;
var
  //lWord: TWord;  TWord is not a standard type!!!
  lColumn: TColumn;  //  semicolon missing
begin

  ClientDataSet1 := TClientDataSet.Create(self);
  //  You need an ID Field if you want to set IndexFieldNames to it !!!
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Brand_trousers', ftstring, 100);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Color', ftstring, 100);

  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';

  //ClientDataSet1.DisableControls;  <- Pointless !!!
  DataSource1.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;
  DBGrid1.Columns.Clear;

  lColumn := TColumn.Create(DBGrid1.Columns);
  lColumn.Width := 40;
  lColumn.Title.Caption := 'ID';
  lColumn.FieldName := 'ID';

  lColumn := TColumn.Create(DBGrid1.Columns);
  lColumn.Width := 40;
  lColumn.Title.Caption := 'Brand trousers';
  lColumn.FieldName := 'Brand_trousers';

  lColumn := TColumn.Create(DBGrid1.Columns);
  lColumn.Width := 150;
  lColumn.Title.Caption := 'Color';
  lColumn.FieldName := 'Color';

  //ClientDataSet1.Append;  <- Pointless when you can add a row and set its
  //  Field values in a single InsertRecord call !!!
  //  Also, Append leaves all the record's field values set to NULL until
  //  you assign other values which is probably why you could see nothing
  //  in the grid
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1, 'Some brand', 'Brown']);
  //ClientDataSet1.EnableControls; <- Pointless
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddLanguage;
end;
```

**Update**

> If that's not a hassle, Please show me how, after selecting a row in the table, throw its contents into TEdit. Eg: Edit1.text "Brand trousers", Edt2.text "Colors

It is easiest if you use TDBEdits rather than TEdits, because they are automatically data-aware.

- Place 3 of them (from the Data Controls tab of the Component Palette) on your form.
- Set the `DataSource` property of each of them to `DataSource1`
- Set their `DataField` properties to `ID`, `Brand_Trousers` and `Color`.

That's all you need to do so that they display data from the current CDS row.  But it's easier if your also add a TDBNavigator to your form and connect it to `DataSource1`, as it includes `Save` and `Cancel` buttons for posting or cancelling changes to the record data.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not wasting any more time on this.  Why couldn't you modify the answer I gave you instead of posting your "answer"?